# Maximize objective function using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

The scipy.optimize module has scipy.optimize.minimize which allows to find value that minimize an objective function. But there is no scipy.optimize.maximize. Why? How do I solve a maximization problem using SciPy?

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb comment but can't you just flip the sign of the objective function and minimize that?

Comment: @SvenHarris That's not a dumb comment. That's the answer to this question. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To maximize `f`, we minimize `-f`. A mini-example, maximizing `f` which is the sine function:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
f = lambda x: np.sin(x)  # function to be MAXIMIZED
res = minimize(lambda x: -f(x), 0)
print('Maximum {} attained at {}'.format(-res.fun, res.x))
```

prints "Maximum 1.0 attained at [1.57079632]".