# Can't figure out how to solve this knapsack problem

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to solve this example of a knapsack problem:

> A Ship has to be packed with containers that have different weights
>   and have different values. The assignment is to find the optimal
>   combination of containers (0-9) to get the most value while still
>   staying within the weight limit of 320.

I can't figure out how to get to this optimal combination of containers with the code I have so far. I can't seem to get any results that could help me find the mistakes in the code or help me understand what's missing.

```
weight = [50, 50, 60, 80, 100, 110, 120, 150, 150, 200]
value    = [80, 80, 60, 50, 100,  90, 100, 170, 200, 240]
n = len(weight)
max_w = 320



def build_items(n):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        items = (weight[i], value[i])
        res.append(items)
    return res

def powerset(items):
    res = [[]]
    for item in items:
        newset = [r+[item] for r in res]
        res.extend(newset)
    return res

def kbf(items, max_weight):
    knapsack = []
    best_weight = 0
    best_value = 0
    for item_set in powerset(items):
        set_weight = sum(e[0] for e in item_set)
        set_value = sum(e[1] for e in item_set)
        if set_value > best_value and set_weight <= max_w:
            best_value = set_value
            best_weight = set_weight
            knapsack = item_set
        return knapsack, best_weight, best_value


data = build_items(n)
print(data)
print(powerset(data))
print(kbf(data,max_w))
```

Printing the last function gives me a really weird output.

Comment: What do you mean by "weird output"? What is weird about it? What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of a 2d Knapsack problem, it can be quickly solved with two nested loops and a (n+1) x (W+1) dimensional DP-Table (Dynamic Programming)

```
DP[x,y] = n x W Table, DP[0,x] = 0 for all x, DP[y,0] = 0 for all y

W = 320
weight = [0....n-1]
value = [0....n-1]

for(i from i=1 to i=n):
    for(w from w=0 to =W):
        if w == 0:
            DP[i,0] = 0
            continue     
        if weight[i] > w:
            DP[i,w] = DP[i-1,w]
            continue
        DP[i,w] = max(DP[i-1,w],DP[i-1,w-weight[i]+value[i])
return DP[n,W]
```

While i cannot assure you that implementing this exact Pseudocode will make it work, that is the general structure of the solution to such a problem. The difficulty always lies in identifying what variables can be used to compute entries based on underlying calculations that have already been made.

You might want to take a look at [Wikipedia about knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem) for additional advise, the sample code for this exact type of problem given there is pretty clean.

Comment: Sorry to stick to you, but I'm trying to give you a one "up", I think I found one. Again such answer might provide a link to the external resource and OP could solve his issue basing on that resource, but SO standard is to at least provide enough information in an answer on which a correct solution could be found (i.e. explaining the problem). Use linking to the external resources as part of "more information" or "as this link says, you can do XYZ". There's no need to provide havily pumped answer (like I did and had some reasons to do so) to provide a good answer.

Comment: I don't mind having you around, thanks for the guidelines/suggestions I was still trying to find out what is about a good middle ground for extensiveness of answers and i guess this helps.

Comment: I just had a feeling if I don't explicitly point out all of the code flaws in that question it could lead the OP to ask more questions and all of them just comes from a some lack of knowledge. Not all questions are about homeworks/assignment but take a look at this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions I think it can give you some ideas on answering (and try looking at the top voted questions on meta some of them also provides nice info for the good answer approaches

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25134617)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @squareskittles
I expanded my answer in the hope of improving it after all

Comment: Just had a small reading on meta and got this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350305/is-very-short-answer-an-answer-or-comment in return, so the final answer for that - it all depends...

Answer (score 0):

You should research linear programming packages like scipy.optimize (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) and gurobipy because you'll need algebra to model the problem correctly and then implement a builtin algorithm like simplex to solve it. In your case you want an integer linear formula because the result is a whole number. So for instance you want to maximize value `max(v)` where v is the sum of all items chosen `maximize sum(vi*xi) for i in range(0,9)` and x is binary to represent whether or not that item is included `c1 = x in (0,1)`. The second constraint for this problem is that the relative weights of each item must sum to less than 320, so `c2 = sum(wi*xi) for i in range(0,9) <= 320`. To maximize a function in simplex you minimize the negative function ([Maximize objective function using scipy.optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974075/maximize-objective-function-using-scipy-optimize)).